# RPI can't connect to internet

Tags: networking, ssh, ethernet, connection

I'm trying to ssh from my mac to my pi but when ssh'ing terminal returns "operation timed out".

`ifconfig` on the Pi returns `192.168.1.10`, but when I ping to that IP I get 100% packet loss.

I've tried rebooting, connecting the ethernet cable directly to my mac (with internet sharing on), the ethernet cable connected to the (time machine) router, `ifup wlan0` (returns interface already configured), inside `/etc/network/interfaces` set up static ip address (`192.168.1.10`)

`nano sbin/ifconfig` returns a bunch of weird symbols.

I don't have internet on the RPi so apt-get update doesn't work.

Could there be something wrong with firewall? And if so, where can I change these settings?

Comment: Are you connected to the same router that you plug in your RPi?

Comment: Yes, my mac is wirelessly connected to my time machine router and my RPi ethernet cable is plugged in to that same router. Also tried connecting to my mac directly (should also work with internet sharing on)

Comment: Can you access the time machine router control panel over the internet? That would help, as we could attempt to turn on port forwarding. That might be an issue, might not.

Comment: nano sbin/ifconfig would try an open the binary executable ifconfig. You run ifconfig -a and it displays  the ip information for all network interfaces.

Comment: what IP address is the Mac/time machine/router? have you tried DHCP, I think its sudo dhclient on the pi?

Comment: time capsule IP: 192.168.0.212
sudo dhclient on rpi returns "file exists"
How can i acces the port forwarding? airport utility gives limited info about time capsule

Comment: Don't fiddle with port forwarding or you will make things worse!

Comment: I dont think that ports are the problem here.

Comment: One big question, have you set your time capsule as a router? "Connect your DSL or cable modem to Time Capsule, then quickly set it up with the easy-to-use AirPort Utility, which is included for both Mac OS X and Windows. Within minutes, you and up to 50 others can use your Mac computers or PCs to surf the web, stream video, share photos, and more — without wires. " - Apple

Comment: yes ofcourse, as my mac is using it as a router. Problem solved by removing static ip adress, plugging into router and reboot.

Comment: I noticed that the router IP range was different that you RPi. So of course he wouldn't work. I was just excluding possibilities before getting to a solution. Glad you solved it.

Comment: I think IP range is ok now: RPi: 192.168.0.107
mac: 192.168.0.219. Should the third number be the same for same network i presume?

Comment: Yes. Think it like this, searching for the same street in different towns. It exists, you just can't find the right place. :D

Answer (score 3):

From your post and comments:

> ... time capsule IP: 192.168.0.212
>
> ... set up static ip address (192.168.1.10)

Your RPi and your Time Capsule are not in the same network. Take a look.

### UPDATE:

So, you would only need to change one or another IP. I didn't mention, as it was implicit in my observation: " ... not in the same network". So, changing Time Capsule to 192.168.**1**.212 or RPi to 192.168.**0**.10 would do the trick.

But, in case you would like a more complete solution, you can download this [wicd-1.7.2.4 package](https://github.com/nicolaiev/wicd-for-raspberry/blob/master/wicd-1.7.2.4.linux-armv6l.tar.gz) (from GitHub) in another computer with internet connection, copy it to RPi **root** (using your console interface and a pendrive to transfer) and doing a:

```
cd /    
sudo tar -zxvf wicd-1.7.2.4.linux-armv6l.tar.gz
```

Or, if you've gotten a connection with your Rpi, you could also try installing and using wicd:

```
sudo apt-get install wicd-curses
```

Now, you are ready to start:

```
sudo wicd-curses
```

You will get a list of wireless networks, found by RPi, and your wired network.

[image: Using wicd with Raspberry Pi]

Then, you can select your wifi or wired network. Just highlight it with arrow keys and press right arrow key to edit its properties.

When you’re done, just press F10 to save it.
It should connect!

Comment: thank you for your answer, it sounds like good solution but the thing is, I don't have internet on my RPi. sudo apt-get won't work..

Comment: I've just updated!

Answer (score 2):

If your RPi IP is 192.168.1.10 and the Time Capsule is 192.168.0.212, they are in different Networks. and if you've set your RPi with a static IP make sure it is correct, just enter the following command,

```
cat /etc/network/interfaces
```

and look for the line

```
iface eth0 inet static
```

Under it you have the address, correct it (in this case 192.168.0.10) and save. Reboot the device and you are good to go.